# Como funciona a função "pop() " em uma pilha?

Tags: c, stack

Gostaria de entender como funciona o `pop` em pilhas.

Só coloquei a parte que não entendi, sei que na função `pop()` há também a verificação de vazia, mas só coloquei a parte que não entendi.

Acontece que essa função que meu professor passou o `p` aponta para `n` e isso só irá sobrescrever quando usado o `push()` e não excluir o valor. Está correto?

```
define MAX = 50;

struct Pilha {
    int n;
    float vet[MAX];
}

float pop(Pilha *p) {
    float v;

    v = p->vet[p->n];
    p->n--;
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Não sei se você sabe que pode votar em tudo site também, além de aceitar uma resposta nas suas perguntas. Veja mais no [tour] do site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está correto, a operação de *pop* em uma pilha tem como função devolver o valor que está no topo da pilha, como ocorre em `v` e abaixar o indicador da pilha para o elemento anterior. Não há necessidade de apagar o dado, ele fica lá inacessível (em condições normais), afinal você não pode acessar um elemento que está acima do elemento mais alto da pilha válida.

Entenda a pilha como caixinhas empilhadas, as caixinhas estão sempre lá, se tem alguma coisa dentro é outra questão. O que importa é o apontador que diz qual é a a caixinha mais alta.

Quando der um *push* na pilha o valor será colocado no elemento que está acima da mais alta atual e colocará em uma caixinha já existente, que tem um valor lá, mas que não importa, você só coloca por cima.

Não precisa limpar algo que não deveria ser acessado mais. Sem outras burocracias pode ser simples assim:

```
float pop(Pilha *p) { return p->vet[p->n--]; }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/StackPop.c).